# In a country's State Lottery, five balls are drawn (without replacement) from a drum filled with balls numbered from 1 to 45.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, hypergeometric-function, lotteries

When buying a ticket an entrant chooses five numbers between 1 and 45 inclusive. To win a prize in a lottery, at least three of the balls drawn
must match numbers on one's ticket. To win the jackpot, all five balls
drawn must match the numbers on one's ticket.

**(a)** What is the probability that a given ticket wins a prize?

**(b)** The population of this country is two million, and on one particular
draw each resident buys one ticket, choosing their numbers at random,
with each ticket being equiprobable, and all residents choose their tickets independently. What is the probability that there are **(i)** no jackpot
winners? **(ii)** exactly one jackpot winner? **(iii)** an even number of jack-
pot winners?

I've already attempted this question but I'd like to check and whether my answers are correct.

**(a)** I used the formula $P(X=k) = \frac{\binom{M}{k}\binom{N-M}{r-k}}{\binom{N}{r}}$ where $N$ is total # of balls, $M$ is # of good balls and $X$ is number of good balls drawn.

Probability of winning would be $P(X≥3) = P(X=3 \cup X=4 \cup X=5) =  P(X=3) + P(X=4) + P(X=5) $

= $\frac{\binom{5}{3}\times \binom{40}{2} + \binom{5}{4}\times \binom{40}{1} + \binom{5}{5}\times \binom{40}{0}}{\binom{45}{5}} = \frac{127}{19393} ≈ 0.00655$

**(b)** **(i)** Binomial Distribution with parameters $n=M$ & $p=\frac{1}{N}$ with $M=2,000,000$ & $N=1,221,759$ .

$P(X=k) = \binom{M}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{M-k}$

So $P(X=0) = (1-p)^{M} = (1-(\frac{1}{N}))^{M} = 0.19456... ≈ 0.1946$

**(ii)** $P(X=k) = \binom{M}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{M-k}$ again so,

$P(X=1) = \binom{M}{1}p(1-p)^{M-1}= 0.318501... ≈ 0.3185$

**(iii)** $P(X=2n) = \binom{M}{2n}p^{2n}(1-p)^{M-2n}$

= $\binom{2,000,000}{2n}\left[\frac{1}{1,221,759}\right]^{2n}\left[1-\frac{1}{1,221,759}\right]^{2000000-2n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$

Are my solutions correct? If not could you please point out where I've made mistakes and how I could go about fixing them?

Thank you for taking the time.

P.S. Apologies for the lack of formatting, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: Let $p$ denote the probability of a single ticket winning jackpot, hence $p=1/\binom{45}{5}$. (i) $\color\red0$ jackpot winners: $\binom{2000000}{\color\red0}\cdot{p}^{\color\red0}\cdot(1-p)^{2000000-\color\red0}$. (ii) $\color\red1$ jackpot winner: $\binom{2000000}{\color\red1}\cdot{p}^{\color\red1}\cdot(1-p)^{2000000-\color\red1}$. (iii) an even number of jackpot winners: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2000000/2}\binom{2000000}{2n}\cdot{p}^{2n}\cdot(1-p)^{2000000-2n}$.

Comment: @barakmanos Thank you, now that you've told me the summation makes perfect sense however why is the sum going from 0-1,000,000 as opposed to from 0-2,000,000?

Comment: The $2n$ "factor" covers for all even elements in the range $0-2000000$.

Comment: @barakmanos Of course! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(a)** I used the formula $P(X=k) = \frac{\binom{M}{k}\binom{N-M}{r-k}}{\binom{N}{r}}$ where $N$ is total # of balls, $M$ is # of good balls and $X$ is number of good balls drawn.

Probability of winning would be $P(X≥3) = P(X=3 \cup X=4 \cup X=5) =  P(X=3) + P(X=4) + P(X=5) $

= $\frac{\binom{5}{3}\times \binom{40}{2} + \binom{5}{4}\times \binom{40}{1} + \binom{5}{5}\times \binom{40}{0}}{\binom{45}{5}} = \frac{127}{19393} ≈ 0.00655$

**(b)** **(i)** Binomial Distribution with parameters $n=M$ & $p=\frac{1}{N}$ with $M=2,000,000$ & $N=1,221,759$ .

$P(X=k) = \binom{M}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{M-k}$

So $P(X=0) = (1-p)^{M} = (1-(\frac{1}{N}))^{M} = 0.19456... ≈ 0.1946$

**(ii)** $P(X=k) = \binom{M}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{M-k}$ again so,

$P(X=1) = \binom{M}{1}p(1-p)^{M-1}= 0.318501... ≈ 0.3185$

**(iii)** $P(X=2n) = \binom{M}{2n}p^{2n}(1-p)^{M-2n}$
= $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2000000/2}\binom{2,000,000}{2n}\left[\frac{1}{1,221,759}\right]^{2n}\left[1-\frac{1}{1,221,759}\right]^{2000000-2n}$

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{r/2}\binom{r}{2n}\cdot{a}^{2n}\cdot{b}^{r-2n} = \frac{(a+b)^r +(a-b)^r}{2}$

So then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2000000/2}\binom{2,000,000}{2n}\left[\frac{1}{1,221,759}\right]^{2n}\left[1-\frac{1}{1,221,759}\right]^{2000000-2n}$

= $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{1221759}+\frac{1221758}{1221759}\right)^{2000000}+\left(\frac{1}{1221759}-\frac{1221758}{1221759}\right)^{2000000}}{2}$

$≈ 0.5189 $